# Creating a Microsoft Teams Meeting using VB.NET and Microsoft Graph API

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created a login authentication using the Microsoft Graph API which means after I sign in, as a result, I have the access token of the current user signed-in. My next step is to create a Microsoft Teams Meeting on behalf of the current user signed-in.

I have tried to follow the Microsoft documentation [Application POST onlinemeetings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp), where It shows the required steps to achieve this scenario.

Unfortunately, they didn't provide an example of how it can be achieved in VB.Net (which is not a big deal because I have converted the code to VB).

Currently, I am stuck on sending a POST request to generate this meeting based on the hard coded values when the user clicks on the button.

Please have a look at the code below:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Net.Http.Headers
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Microsoft.Graph
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Private Shared httpClient As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
    Private Shared context As AuthenticationContext = Nothing
    Private Shared credential As ClientCredential = Nothing
    Private Shared graphClient As GraphServiceClient
    Private Shared authprovider As IAuthenticationProvider

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim code = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("Code")
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            If code <> "" Then
                Dim url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token"
                Dim myParameters = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" & code & "&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4312/&client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET"
                Dim wb = New WebClient
                wb.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType) = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                Dim response = wb.UploadString(url, "POST", myParameters)
                responseToken.Text = response
                Success.Text = "O365 login successful. Below is the response token"
                Dim SurroundingClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of SurroundingClass)(response)


                Dim rss As JObject = JObject.Parse(response)
                Dim token = rss.SelectToken("access_token")
                Dim res = GetUsers(token)



            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Shared Async Function GetUsers(ByVal result As String) As Task(Of String)
        Try
            Dim users As String = Nothing
            Dim querystring As String = "api-version=1.6"
            Dim uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result)
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))

            Dim User = GetMeAsync().Result
            Console.WriteLine($"Welcome {User.DisplayName}!\n")

            Dim getResult = Await httpClient.GetAsync(uri)

            If getResult.Content IsNot Nothing Then
                users = Await getResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
            End If

            Return users
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function

      Protected Sub tes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Try

            'Dim fr As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
            Dim client_id = ""// App Client ID'
            Dim uri = "https://localhost:4312/"

            Dim targetURI As String = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=" & client_id &
                                     "&redirect_uri=" & uri & "&response_type=code&scope=openid+Mail.Read"
            Response.Redirect(targetURI)

        Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
            'Error in accessing the resource, handle it
        End Try
    End Sub

       Public Shared Async Function CreateMeeting() As Task(Of OnlineMeeting)

    Try
        graphClient = New GraphServiceClient(authprovider)

        Dim onlineMeeting = New OnlineMeeting With {
            .StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-04-23T21:33:30.8546353+00:00"),
            .EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-04-23T22:03:30.8566356+00:00"),
            .Subject = "Application Token Meeting",
            .Participants = New MeetingParticipants With {
            .Organizer = New MeetingParticipantInfo With {
            .Identity = New IdentitySet With {
                .User = New Identity With {
                    .Id = "MYID"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

        Dim encodings As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim arrayJson As String = serializer.Serialize(onlineMeeting)
        Dim result As String = Nothing

        Dim postRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings"), HttpWebRequest)
        postRequest.Method = "POST"
        postRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Token)

        If postRequest.Method = "POST" Then

            Dim parsedContent As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(onlineMeeting)
            Dim encoding As ASCIIEncoding = New ASCIIEncoding()
            Dim bytes As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(parsedContent)
            Dim newStream As Stream = postRequest.GetRequestStream()
            newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            newStream.Close()

        End If

        Dim createMeetings = Await graphClient.Communications.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting)

        Console.WriteLine("The meeting has been created")

        Return createMeetings

    Catch ex As ServiceException

        Console.WriteLine($"Error while creating the meeting: {ex.Message}")
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function

  Public Sub InvokeMeeting(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


    Try
        Dim testing = CreateMeeting()


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    End Sub
```

PS: I have added the permission required to call this API to be able to create a Teams meeting.

Any suggestions on how to achieve the following scenario?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: it's unclear specifically what problem/error your code is experiencing. You said you're "stuck" somehow. Can you be more precise and detailed please? What is going wrong for you?

Comment: Hello @ADyson, I want to know how can i send a POST request to call the onlineMeeting API based on the current user signed-in, inside the createMeeting function in my code. So when the button is triggered I want to create the meeting based on these hard coded values.I hope you have understood my issue.

Comment: Well, what is stopping you from doing it, exactly? From the code you've shown it seems you already know how to create a POST request using VB.NET. So just follow the documentation in the link you gave, to structure your request appropriately. Either that or use the graph client throughout your code, to generate requests on your behalf using the structured methods and classes it provides. You seem to have got some of it using your own HTTP requests, and some using the graph client. Either use the client, or create your own requests, not both. A half-and-half approach will not work very well.

Comment: Hello @ADyson, Actually while debugging nothing happens which means the meeting is not created based on the current user signed in, knowing that I have followed the documentation step by step, could you please have a look at the updated code above I might miss something to add or I am doing something wrong. Your help is greatly appreciated.